# How can I create http outbound-gateway with JAVA config in Spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have the following http outbound gateway. How can I do this configuration with Java Config or Spring DSL?

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="test"
                           url="http://localhost:8080/"
                           http-method="POST"
                           charset="UTF-8"
                           header-mapper="soapHeaderMapper"
                           request-factory="requestFactory"
                           request-channel="inputChannel"/>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow httpOut() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("inputChannel")
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8080/")
                    .charset("UTF-8")
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .headerMapper(soapHeaderMapper())
                    .requestFactory(requestFactory()), e -> e.id("test"))
            .get();
}
```

Or

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="inputChannel")
@Bean(name="test")
public MessageHandler httpout() {
    HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler = new ...
    ...
    return handler;
}
```

Comment: How to decide which one is better? I hope both provide similar customization and offer similar readability. Any thoughts?

Comment: Most people prefer the java DSL (the first) or XML over the annotation model. At runtime there is no difference between all 3 methods. So it is all about user preference.