# How to create int-http:outbound-gateway without xml configuration

Tags: spring, http, spring-integration, outbound

How to convert below spring integration XML configuration into java configuration beans.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd">

    <int:channel id='reply.channel'>
        <int:queue capacity='10' />
    </int:channel>
    <int:channel id='get.request.channel'/>

    <int-http:outbound-gateway id="outbound.gateway"
                               request-channel="get.request.channel" url="{fhirurl}"
                               http-method-expression="payload.getHttpMethod()" expected-response-type-expression="payload.getResponseType()"
                               charset="UTF-8" reply-timeout="5000" reply-channel="reply.channel">

        <int-http:uri-variable name="fhirurl" expression="payload.getUrl()"/>

    </int-http:outbound-gateway>

</beans>
```

I got below code but not able to use
Can you help me what to write inside soapHeaderMapper and requestFactory

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow httpOut() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("reply.channel")
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8080/")
                        .charset("UTF-8")
                        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                        .headerMapper(soapHeaderMapper())
                        .requestFactory(requestFactory()), e -> e.id("test"))
                .get();
    }
```

Advance Thank you

Comment: Your question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055723/how-can-i-create-http-outbound-gateway-with-java-config-in-spring-integration) question.

Comment: yes but I am not able to implement that. what is soapHeaderMapper() and requestFactory() can you provide sample for that